# How to install react-navigation in an ejected expo project?

Tags: java, android, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I am trying to install `react-navigation` in my ejected expo app by following the official install instructions on [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html) page. Within the instructions below the typical addition of the package and linking via `react-native link` there is additional code to be added into the file `MainActivity.java`.

Now my problem is that in the install instructions the class `MainActivity` extends the class `ReactActivity`, **but since I use an ejected expo app in my code it extends the class `DetachActivity`**, which seems to be incompatible with the given code of the install instruction and therefore I am really clueless how to approach that incompatibility problem (especially since I am not even able to find anything via google about that - is it even [a dark secret nobody talks about](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2775)?).

Some approaches I tried but did not work:

- Including code anyways produces error [compiling error] `error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype`.
- Including code, replacing `DetachActivity` with `ReactActivity` and removing all methods overriding methods of `DetachActivity` results in crash of the app.
- Not including anything produces error [*red screen on phone*] `Native module com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerModule tried to override versioned.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerModule for module name RNGestureHandlerModule. Check the getPackages() method in MainApplication.java, it might be that module is being created twice. If this was your intention, set canOverrideExistingModule=true`.

I would really appreciate some wise tips! Also, I am not very familiar with java but am totally willing to learn some new stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update in Dec. 2019

Ignore below. 
Expo is separating their built in dependencies as react-native-gesture-handler nowadays. So we need to install it.
[Ref](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html#installing-dependencies-into-a-bare-react-native-project)

## Solution

To summarize,

Go back to a commit you ejected a project from expo. And install `react-navigation`. 
Do not install others as `react-native-gesture-handler`.

That's all.

## Why

If you ejected your project from expo, those projects will have dependencies on ExpoKit, so do not need to install modules again already built. And `react-native-gesture-handler` is the one of those modules. 
Thus, do not need `react-native link` also.

`Native module com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerModule tried to override versioned.host.exp.exponent.modules.api.components.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerModule for module name RNGestureHandlerModule. Check the getPackages() method in MainApplication.java, it might be that module is being created twice. If this was your intention, set canOverrideExistingModule=true.`

And this message may caused by `RNGestureHandlerModule` you installed again.

Comment: Thank you, this actually helped a lot! Seems like I really messed my project up, but could get it working by creating a completely new expo project, eject from there and put in all my stuff in.

Comment: @PeterLehnhardt :). You will do not same mistake. Happy coding!

Comment: Unable to resolve "react-native-gesture-handler" from "node_modules/@react-navigation/native/src/Scrollables.js"

Comment: @Pencilcheck Expo is separating their built in dependencies as react-native-gesture-handler nowadays. So you need to install it. [Ref](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html#installing-dependencies-into-a-bare-react-native-project)